# ASP.Net object reference error when writing data to xml file via Gridview Empty data template

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, gridview

I have an Editable GridView control that functions off of an XML file. The GridView contains an empty-data-template given that the xml file contains no data on page load. The empty-data-template consist of two textbox controls and a link-button for placing data into the xml file, and thus should cause the Gridview to display. My problem is that when I click the link button, I get an Object-reference related error in response to this line: **Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow**  ...the full event handler, I provided below:

**The code behind:**

```
Public Sub writeStartpoNum()
        Dim startpoNumID As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNumID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim startpoNum As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNum"), TextBox).Text
        Dim oDs As New DataSet()
        Dim xmlPath As String = MapPath("~/xml/newShipment.xml")
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath) Then
            oDs.DataSetName = "newShipmentNotification"
            oDs.Tables.Add("pos")
            oDs.Tables("pos").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
            oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
            oDs.Tables.Add("po")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumberID")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumber")
            Dim pos_po As DataRelation = oDs.Relations.Add("pos_po", oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id"), _
            oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id"))
            pos_po.Nested = True
            Dim oDrs As DataRow = oDs.Tables("pos").NewRow
            oDrs("pos_Id") = 0
            oDs.Tables("pos").Rows.Add(oDrs)
        Else
            oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newShipment.xml"))
        End If
        Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow
        oDr("ponumberID") = startpoNumID
        oDr("ponumber") = startpoNum
        oDr("pos_Id") = 0
        oDs.Tables("po").Rows.Add(oDr)
        oDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newShipment.xml"))
        gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataSource = oDs.Tables("po")
        gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

...this is the design for the empty-data-template in the Gridview:

```
<emptydatatemplate>
<b>Enter Purchase Order Number:</b> <br /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartpoNumID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartpoNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkpro" runat="server" OnClick="writeStartpoNum"  Text="Add Purchase order Number"></asp:LinkButton> 
<br /><br />
</emptydatatemplate>
```

...this is how the xml reflects on page load as a results of a function that clears the xml file of any data if the xml file contains data on page load.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<newShipmentNotification>
  <pos />
</newShipmentNotification>
```

...As I mentioned, when debugged - the issue stems from the following line

Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow

The xml is build out, via the conditional statement. What I cannot figure is why the dataset variable (oDs), even though it reflects the **pos** table when viewed in debug mode, still generates an object-reference related error. Please provide some direction as to what I may be doing wrong here or if there is something I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you have the xml file without 'po' node. You can move the node to a new 
method like:

```
Private Function CreatePOSDataset() As DataSet
        Dim oDs As New DataSet()
        oDs.DataSetName = "newshipmentnotification"
        oDs.Tables.Add("pos")
        oDs.Tables("pos").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
        oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        oDs.Tables.Add("po")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumberID")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("pos_Id")
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns.Add("ponumber")

        Dim pos_po As DataRelation = oDs.Relations.Add("pos_po", oDs.Tables("pos").Columns("pos_Id"), _
        oDs.Tables("po").Columns("pos_Id"))
        pos_po.Nested = True

        Dim oDrs As DataRow = oDs.Tables("pos").NewRow
        oDrs("pos_Id") = 0
        oDs.Tables("pos").Rows.Add(oDrs)
        CreatePOSDataset = oDs
    End Function
```

And call the method when 'po' node does not exist:

```
Public Sub writeStartpoNum(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim startpoNumID As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNumID"), TextBox).Text
        Dim startpoNum As String = DirectCast(gvPurchaseOrderNum.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("txtStartpoNum"), TextBox).Text

    Dim oDs As New DataSet()
    Dim xmlPath As String = MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml")

    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath) Then
        oDs = CreatePOSDataset()
    Else
        oDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
        If oDs.Tables("po") Is Nothing Then
            oDs = CreatePOSDataset()
        End If
    End If
    Dim oDr As DataRow = oDs.Tables("po").NewRow
    oDr("ponumberID") = startpoNumID
    oDr("ponumber") = startpoNum
    oDr("pos_Id") = 0
    oDs.Tables("po").Rows.Add(oDr)
    oDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/newshipmentnotification.xml"))
    gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataSource = oDs.Tables("po")
    gvPurchaseOrderNum.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I get an error: BC30491: Expression does not produce a value. I notice that the method was called under a different name in the the "writeStartpoNum" event handler so I modified CreatePOSDataset() to reflect CreateNodePos(), though I did not expect a change in the error. Anything that I might be overlooking here?

Comment: Good catch! I have corrected my answer. Name the method CreatePOSDataset() instead of CreateNodePOS()

Comment: All is still well. I have a question though. I will be adding two more Gridviews, all using the same xml file. I already added one of them and created a new method for it using the approach above. It functions well, but I notice when I add data via one of the GVs event methods, the data for the other GV is removed from the xml file. I figured that since the XML file now exists via the execution of the first method, that the second method/grid would just write its data/table under the first.  What must be done to the event methods so that all Grids may use the same file? Thanks Again

Comment: Probably you are using other nodes than pos in xml. In our procedures we are creating pos node only. So other nodes are lost. You can email me the xml, code and markup. I will be happy to assist.

Comment: Thanks again, is this the address: afzalulhb@gmail.com

Comment: ... I've emailed it over